# Calling a function through onClick in HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-manipulation, function-call

With DOM manipulation we access our html elements and add the according functionality to it. But is there a way (I couldn't think of a use case but just curious) to do it the other way around? So imagine we had our function in index.js

```
function sayHi(){
   alert('hi')
}
```

and our index.js connected to our index.html, could we then somehow call the function on the element itself? Because the following works:

```
<button onClick="alert('hi')">click me</button>
```

So is there a way to do something like:

```
<button onClick="sayHi()">click me</button>
```

and make that work?

Comment: there is, but let's do that on the JS side, instead of using the ancient `onclick` attribute on the HTML side. MDN has an [excellent, nice and short page that teaches you proper event handling](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers).

Comment: With  `onClick` there is zero difference between caling a function, or calling *functionality* -- It's all about cleaner, more efficient code, and that's why we use functions.  But as Mike mentioned, I would be using some sort of even handling if possible instead of `onClick`

Comment: Thanks guys! Yes, I know we shouldn't do that. I was just wondering and when I tried, it didn't work. Although the function is in the global scope of my index.js

When I click the button, it says "sayHi" is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible as long as the function you're calling is in the global scope.

```js
function sayHi(){
   alert('hi')
}
```

```html
<button onClick="sayHi()">click me</button>
```

However if you're maintaining a larger application, you should probably use a declarative framework like React, Vue, Angular, or Svelte.